# Codeigniter when does result_array() return a single or multi dimensional array?

Tags: php, codeigniter

On returning $query->result_array(); 
Sometime I get multiple single arrays like this:

```
Array
(
    [user_id] => 32
    [username] => johnd
    [cat_id] => 7
)
Array
(
    [user_id] => 33
    [username] => Janed
    [cat_id] => 6

)
```

While sometimes i get multidimensional arrays like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 33
            [username] => Janed
            [cat_id] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 32
            [username] => Johnd
            [cat_id] => 7
        )

)
```

Is it something to do with the query, is there a specificreason for this?

Comment: Isn't that first example also an array of arrays?  How do you reference the second one?  Also maybe you are calling result_array() and row_array().  See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Comment: The first one just returns the each column in an array(which makes life easy btw), the second returns the columns in an array withing an array. Yh i checked that as well but both of them are result_array() :(

Comment: What do you mean by "sometimes"? How are you iterating / printing the result?  Are you *sure* you are calling `result_array`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: that's a very good question. I ran some tests and i found out that it does indeed depend on how the result is printed.

Comment: @Saff: `result_array` *always* returns a 2D array.  Depending on how you loop/view it, it may *look* different, but it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$query->result_array()` **always** returns you a 2D array (unless the database returns no results, then it returns an empty array).

It returns you an array of "result" arrays.  Each result array contains that row's fields.

Docs: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html