# PHP Query Array Without Header (CI using MySQL DB)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello everyone i have some question about query on PHP using MySQL database.

I have table name test2 like this

```
testid  asd
1       A
2       B
3       C
4       D
```

and then i have query like this

```
public function m_get_wer() {
    $sql = "SELECT `asd` FROM test2";
    $data = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
    return $data;
}
```

when i used print_r on that query, the result like this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [asd] => A ) [1] => Array ( [asd] => B ) [2] => Array ( [asd] => C ) [3] => Array ( [asd] => D ) )
```

but the result that i need is like this

```
Array ( [0] => A [1] => B [2] => C [3] => D )
```

How i can get result like that. thanks.

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896633/codeigniter-when-does-result-array-return-a-single-or-multi-dimensional-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter when does result\_array() return a single or multi dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896633/codeigniter-when-does-result-array-return-a-single-or-multi-dimensional-array)

Comment: @Maykonn so whats the solution? is it possible i get result like i want? Array ( [0] => A [1] => B [2] => C [3] => D )

Comment: Is not possible with codeigniter functions, I guess. You need a loop like @pradeep answered. Codeigniter provide to you an array like it because is expected that you will use the array values in this way for example: echo $result[0]["asd"]. I recommend you to write a new layer between your data access layer and your business code to translate the responses of queries in a way that make sense for your business code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you :

```
public function m_get_wer()
    {   
        $sql = "SELECT asd FROM test2";
        $data = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();

        if ($data)
        {
            foreach ($data as $key => $item) 
            {
                $result[$key] = $item['asd'];
            }
        }
        //print_r($result);die;
        return $result;
    }
```

Output will be :

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
)
```

Comment: wow thank you so much. its work. but can you tell me how thats work? i just want to know. Thanks

Comment: $data is the array of array to get the item of inner array a foreach loop is needed to loop through

Comment: what if i want to select 2 column like testid and asd. the result like this Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => A ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => B ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => C ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => D ) )

Comment: Like this?
if ($data)
        {
            foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
                $result[$key] = $item['testid'];
                $result[$key] = $item['asd'];
            }
        }
i already try that, but result just same like before, return Array ( [0] => A [1] => B [2] => C [3] => D )
sorry im not expert at coding

Comment: if u want both testid and asd then change sql as select * from test2 or select testid, asd  from test2 and u will get the desired result

Comment: ya i already do that, change select * from test 2. but the result like this Array ( [0] => Array ( [testid] => 1 [asd] => A ) [1] => Array ( [testid] => 2 [asd] => B ) [2] => Array ( [testid] => 3 [asd] => C ) [3] => Array ( [testid] => 4 [asd] => D ) ) without foreach like you do before. i need testid become 0 and asd become 1

Comment: do you want to change the value of testid and asd means change ur database values

Comment: no, i mean from this  Array ( [0] => Array ( [testid] => 1 [asd] => A ) [1] => Array ( [testid] => 2 [asd] => B ) [2] => Array ( [testid] => 3 [asd] => C ) [3] => Array ( [testid] => 4 [asd] => D ) ).        Become to this Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => A ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => B ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => C ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => D ) )